# После обновления Android Studio до 3.5.3 перестал работать эмулятор

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk, android-emulator

Выдаёт ошибку
Emulator: PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value

Каталог c SDK никуда не переносил, пакеты все установлены, переменные среды ANDROID_SDK_ROOT и ANDROID_HOME устанавливал - не помогает.
Ставил 3.5.3 начисто, обновлялся до беты 3.6 - всё равно ошибка остаётся.

Comment: Если создать новое виртуальное устройство - тоже не работает?

Comment: Тоже не работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема, скорей всего кроется в кириллических символах, в пути к папке C:\Users\user_name\ .android\avd. В моём случае user_name на кириллице. Также делал всё, менял системные переменные, переустанавливал Android Studio, не помогало. После долгих мучений, перенёс папку avd в другой путь, без кириллицы. И всё заработало. Перенос папки делал по этой инструкции - https://www.mysysadmintips.com/windows/clients/761-move-android-studio-avd-folder-to-a-new-location

Comment: У меня тоже папка пользователя состоит из кириллицы. Попробую и ваш вариант, хотя есть 2 но:
1. Раньше всё прекрасно работало с папкой AVD в профиле с кириллицей
2. Переносить папку AVD я уже пробовал, только по другому: переносим папку в новое место; указываем путь к ней в ini файле. Сам ini остаётся в профиле пользователя, но эмулятор виртуальное устройство видит (хоть и по прежнему не запускает)

Comment: @АлексейБ, здесь уже было не мало вопросов, где в студии что-то переставало работать из-за кириллицы именно после обновлений. Но других решений, кроме перемещения папок или смены юзер-нейма на латиницу не припомню. Лично я и без студии не раз выгребал проблемы в других приложениях из-за этого - поэтому давно перевёл имя пользователя на латиницу и забыл про них.

Comment: Заработало, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема действительно в кириллических символах, но не обязательно что-то куда-то переносить, можно воспользоваться следующим лайфхаком.

Копируете название папки из сообщения об ошибки, например в консоли Android Studio. В моем случае, имя папки было "Никита", а в сообщении было "РќРёРєРёС‚Р°"

Далее открываете командную строку и создаете хардлинк.

```
mklink /J "C:\Users\РќРёРєРёС‚Р°" "C:\Users\Никита"
```

Готово!

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло зайти в config.ini и ИМЯ_МОДЕЛИ.ini и поменять старые пути до SDK, предварительно перенеся папку .android в папку с установленным SDK и да , проблема с русскими символами является основной.