# Не удается запустить созданный проект React Native

Tags: android, react-native

При попытке запуска на андроид выдает такую ошибку:
Операционная система - Windows

:ReactNative:Unexpected empty result of running '[node, C:\Users\io332\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\ReactNative\secondTestProject\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command.
:ReactNative:Running '[node, C:\Users\io332\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\ReactNative\secondTestProject\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Users\io332\OneDrive\������� ����\ReactNative\secondTestProject\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 413
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating script.

> node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1056  throw err;  ^Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\io332\OneDrive\Р Р°Р±РѕС‡РёР№ СЃС‚РѕР»\ReactNative\secondTestProject\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js'    at Module._reso
> lveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1053:15)    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:898:27)    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:84:12)    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',  requireStack: []}Node.js v19.4.0

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
:ReactNative:Unexpected empty result of running '[node, C:\Users\io332\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\ReactNative\secondTestProject\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command.
:ReactNative:Running '[node, C:\Users\io332\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\ReactNative\secondTestProject\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Users\io332\OneDrive\������� ����\ReactNative\secondTestProject\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 413
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating script.

> node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1056  throw err;  ^Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\io332\OneDrive\Р Р°Р±РѕС‡РёР№ СЃС‚РѕР»\ReactNative\secondTestProject\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js'    at Module._reso
> lveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1053:15)    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:898:27)    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:84:12)    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',  requireStack: []}Node.js v19.4.0

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s

```
at makeError (C:\Users\io332\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\ReactNative\secondTestProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
at C:\Users\io332\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\ReactNative\secondTestProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\io332\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\ReactNative\secondTestProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\io332\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\ReactNative\secondTestProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:142:9)
```

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Похоже проблема в кириллице (Рабочий стол), посмотрите ответы к этому вопросу: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1057141/11515

Answer (score 0):

У вас не установлены переменные среды для работы андрода (Android development environment). Вам нужно сделать это например вот так https://developer.android.com/design-for-safety/privacy-sandbox/setup
В этом способе не нужно работать с консолью, все должно само поставится, нужно просто скачать андроид студио и последовать инструкции.

Если у вас уже есть адроид студио и вы уверенны что sdk уже установлен, нужно работать с консолью. Для начала нужно проверить прав ли я, для этого в консоли

для мак и линукс

```
echo $ANDROID_HOME
```

Если там пусто - можете дать мне знать здесь